# Python: shuffle within a for loop shuffles the same way every time

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I have a list of numbers [1,2,3,4,5]. I would like to make a list, containing different permutations of [1,2,3,4,5] (i.e it would be a list of lists).

For example, I want something like 
[[1,4,5,3,2], [3,1,4,5,2],[ 5,1,2,4,3]].

```
import random
from random import shuffle

superlist = []
littlelist = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(1, 4):
    random.shuffle(little_list)
    superlist.append(little_list)
print(superlist)
```

This outputs

```
[[2, 5, 4, 3, 1], [2, 5, 4, 3, 1], [2, 5, 4, 3, 1]]
```

So within my for loop, the 'random shuffle' produces the same thing. I tried time seeding it, but there was the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `random.shuffle` you shuffle the list in place, you aren't making a copy. Then you append `little_list` to `superlist` but every time you shuffle it you are shuffling the same list.

Try appending a copy then you'll see the differences:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    random.shuffle(little_list)
    superlist.append(list(little_list))
print(superlist)
```

Everything in Python works by manipulating references to objects: when you put an object (e.g. `little_list`) into another object all you are doing is making `superlist` hold a reference to the original `little_list`. Python never ever makes a copy of an object unless you specifically ask it to copy the object. You can copy a list easily by calling the `list(...)` constructor, but even that only copies the references from the original, so if you were to copy `superlist` and manipulate the lists it contains you would still see those changes back in the original `superlist`.

Comment: I'm aware that I'm shuffling the same list, but I figured that if it were randomly shuffling it, I'll be appending different things to the superlist.

Comment: No, you're superlist is just `[little_list, little_list, little_list]`, same sublist each time, every change you make to `little_list` is visible 3 times in `superlist`.

Comment: I see. So your method, instead of appending little_list, appends a copy of little_list that has just been shuffled. Shuffling little_list again does not affect this copy. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can copy it before or after shuffling but the important thing is that each copy is a separate object so they may be changed independently whereas in your original code they are all the same object just referenced by different routes.